# Java - retrieve object of certain class

Tags: java

For some time I'm programming in J2ME. I wanna create "super" game 2D now. At first take most important data:

- game is shooting where you go with soldier and fire to enemies
- each soldier is once object of `Soldier` class (inherits after `Sprite`)
- each soldier is able to generate bullet - objects of `Bullet` class (inherits after `Sprite`, too)

And I got problem here. It's so: bullet hits in soldier. How I can transfer soldier's object to bullet's object (or vice versa) to decrease HP of soldier.

Next data at glance:

- `Soldier` class have got static field `HP`
- `Bullet` class have got static field `hit` contains data about bullet's force

I've conditional statement that check whether player collides with trpas - TiledLayer. It is not no problem. Problem is checking collison with bullets.  `collidesWith()` method checks collides with once object of `Sprite`, `TiledLayer`, `Layer`. And bullet's objects will be a lot. Is here such option to check collision with certain type and not with certain object of certain type (not check collision with bullet1, bullet2, bullet3 as queue, and with all what is type of `Bullet`)?

My questions.

1.How I can transfer Bullet's data to Soldier if collision occured?
 2. How I can detect collision with `Bullet` type, not with object this type x bullet number?

Answer (score 0):

The `Object` class has a [getClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) method which returns the name of the class of which the given Object is an instance. It's not the best programming practice, but it works. If you need to "transfer" `Bullet` data to a `Soldier`, add a collision method that accepts a bullet / soldier: `soldierCollisionEvent(Bullet b)`, or even `collision(Soldier s, Bullet b)`. Alternatively, you can utilize [object-oriented programming](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/) to let objects share data and events without worrying (too much) about class types.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have reflection in J2ME, so there is no `Bullet.class` or anything similar.

Even if there were, it still wouldn't help since you would still have to (somehow) check all the bullets.

However, you could try doing some more intelligent stuff like tracking a few bullets that you know are closer to the `Soldier`. If you feel like it you can even try advanced algorithms/data structures for space partitioning ([k-d trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree), or [BVH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume_hierarchy)), which are very well documented for 3D computer graphics and are much simpler when used in 2D.

Good luck!

Edit: There's no need for the all the fancy stuff if you have just an handful of bullets (say 10). It would only complicate things, just checking collisions for each bullet should be fine.